# JQuery preventDefault() using ajax, .on, form, class and future elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that is created dynamically, then I need to submit it using AJAX with `preventDefault()`.

If I use below code, it works.

```
$('#container').on('submit', 'form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: /myurl,
        data: $(this).serialize()
   });
});
```

But I need to submit using a class, as below, so doing it `preventDefault()` doesn't work. Is there any workaround for this?

```
$('#container').on('submit', '.ajax-form', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: /myurl,
        data: $(this).serialize()
   });
});
```

A short HTML is:

```
<div id="container">
    <form action="/foo/bar" class="ajax-form" method="post">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Both will work fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/5CH6C/ and http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/5CH6C/1/.

Comment: why preventdefault? you don't want to reload page? and, BTW, preventdefault prevent the submit, not the execution of the code in the same function, so console.log SHALL be executed no matter what....

Comment: @Unknown, It isn't: http://jsfiddle.net/5CH6C/3/

Comment: @CrisimIlNumenoreano, Yes, i am submiting via ajax because i don't want to reload the page.

Comment: I guess you are confused with `return` and `preventDefault`. When a `preventDefault` is encountered the basic nature of the event (here the submit) will be stopped. It does not mean the fore-coming lines will be executed.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS, I made some updates in the question, please take a look

Comment: You can rewrite your code as in this Fiddle, it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/5CH6C/4/

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS, Based in your comment i found a solution, many thanks! It is here: http://jsfiddle.net/5CH6C/6/ Please post your comment as an answer, then i will mark it as the best.

Comment: Your "solution" is exactly the same as want you already posted. Which selector you use to match the form element doesn't matter.

Comment: @FelixKling, The difference was the prefix `form` that Viswalinga Surya S suggested. So the final selector was `form.ajax-submit`. That made the things to work.

Comment: And I said, the selector **doesn't matter**. As you can see here, http://jsfiddle.net/5CH6C/7/, preventing the default event works perfectly fine with only a class. If that change really made it work, then that's a coincidence, and the more important question is, what is the real issue.

Comment: @FelixKling, Actually, the right example is http://jsfiddle.net/5CH6C/6/ My firtst explanation wasn't good, in a few words, i was trying to stop the basic nature of the event submit, because i was using an AJAX submit.

Comment: I understand that. But the default submit event is still prevented, no matter which selector you use. What else you do in the event handler doesn't matter either.

Comment: @FelixKling, Maybe it is a version issue, because if i use `form.ajax-form` the things work as i expect, but if i use `.ajax-form` they don't work. I am using JQuery 1.11.0 with JQuery Migrate 1.2.1

Comment: This may not be version issues. May be you assigned the class `ajax-form` for some other elements in your project, which arises a conflict. `form.ajax-form` restricts this and adds the listener only for the form.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:
Sorry for the vague response. My code example was to basically show what *would* work when using `preventDefault()` on a form submission. That being said, the only thing would actually prevent your event from avoiding the default action is: you're not targeting the correct form or you have a JS syntax error somewhere else in your code. Syntactically, you're good.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.ajax-form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Do other stuff
});
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: I don't have a new question.

Comment: Do you just want to show us how nicely you can format code or is the actually an attempt to solve the OPs problem? If so, how? What's wrong in the OPs code and why does your "solution" solve it?

Comment: Ouch! I will post a more detailed answer. Wanted to show basically what would work.

Comment: But why wouldn't the OPs code not work? I don't see anything wrong with it. To be clear: I don't disagree that your code works as we'll, I just don't think it's relevant to the problem.

Comment: Syntax-wise, I'll admit, I don't see an error. I should have probably posted a question or comment instead.